# Right align text in an HTML.TextAreaFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

How to right align arabic text in TextArea? For TextBox dir = "rtl" property works fine. But for TextArea it is not.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DescriptionAr, new { @class = "control-label" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DescriptionAr)
      @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DescriptionAr, 10, 10, new { @class = "ckeditor form-control", dir = "rtl" })
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the ckeditor plugin from this textarea and see whether you are getting the expected behavior.

Comment: @Shyju after removing ckeditor plugin it works fine, but i need this plugin. Is there any way to right align text using this plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i solved it by changing the config settings of the "CKEDITOR" plugin.

HTML Code:

```
  <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DescriptionAr, new { @class = "control-label" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DescriptionAr)
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DescriptionAr, 10, 10, new { @class = "ckeditor form-control", id = "descArEditor" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('descArEditor',
        {
            contentsLangDirection: 'rtl'
        });
```